# What should be done in terms of sampling (sample size, power of test...) when comparing two paired groups with unknown distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, sample-size

#### Context

I have two paired groups and I want to test whether their **means** are equal or not. I cannot assume normality of the distributions of both groups/distribution of the differences.

#### Variables

The random variable of the study is the processing time of datasets on a cluster of machines (parallel proccessing). (Data processing on the cloud)

#### Study Objective

Although the *mean* may seem not the appropriate statistic to compare since I don't know the underlying distribution, it is the most appropriate because outliers and how skewed the distribution is doesn't matter for the experiment goal, which is to reduce the *mean* time.

#### Limitations

1. I don't have enough budget for *n* > 20
2. I don't know the underlying distribution and I either don't know the estimated population std, since I don't have any samples to estimate it before the experiment

#### How to estimate sample size and power?

What is the most appropriate approach?

1. Proceed with a fixed sample size because I do not know the distribution (therefore AFAIK I can't calculate a sample size), e.g. 15 elements, and present the power of the test (considering a gaussian distribution, because again AFAIK it is very hard or not possible to calculate power of unknown distribution) using an estimated variance from the samples, regardless of the result (rejecting or not)
2. Proceed with a pilot study embarked on the experiment, for example, start the experiment, on the 10th element take a estimated variance, calculate the sample size using this estimation and the desired power & effect size, continue the experimentation until the calculated *n* or 20 elements (limitation because of the budget). If *n* > 20, naturally I'll need to recalculate the power considering the sample I have (20, max)
3. Other, please specify or point to a paper/stackexhange question

**Obs: In the case I use a non parametric test, such as Wilcoxon Signed Rank, could I simply calculate the sample size for parametric tests and add an buffer of 15% in the sample size, accordingly to [graphpad tutorial](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/statistics/stat_sample_size_for_nonparametric_.htm)?*

#### How the inadequate sample size affects Error Type I when rejecting the null hypothesis?

Additionally, does the sample size affect the error type I rate? i.e., if I reject the null hypothesis with a fixed sample of 15 elements, can I state that the probability of making an error under the null hypothesis is still alfa?

I could find some references on SE [Should you be concerned with statistical power if you reject the null hypothesis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/377307/should-you-be-concerned-with-statistical-power-if-you-reject-the-null-hypothesis)
[Should I bother that t-test power is relatively small when H0 is already rejected?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156039/should-i-bother-that-t-test-power-is-relatively-small-when-h0-is-already-rejecte)
and all of those replies advocate against doing it after the experimentation or conducting an experimentation with low power. But what if I can't have high power due to my budget limitations?

Comment: 2. Sounds like a bad idea. You don't want your sample size to depend on your sample (or part of it).

Comment: Agreed. What about 1? Or do you have anything to share?

Comment: 1. You generally don't need to know the distribution of the data to estimate power. Rather you rely on the CLT to say that asymptotically the means are normally distributed. (The problem is usually estimating the effect size.)  In your case, your sample is probably too small to rely on asymptotics. I'd say just make the sample as large as you possibly can.

Comment: "I don't know the underlying distribution therefore I don't know the estimated population std" - this is incorrect; the estimated population std can be calculated based on the "usual" formula and is an unbiased estimator (at least when the population has a finite variance!)

Comment: Can you assume anything "nice" about the distribution of the outcome, such as bounded support, or at light tails? Then using the CLT , as @num_39 suggested, should already be ok for your small sample size / / Your suggestion 2. is called "sample size re-estimation" (ssr) , and is actually used in clinical trials - not a bad idea in general, but may require assumptions about the distribution, and larger sample sizes (I don't know more about it, other than it may affect type 1 error, but there are methods to cope) / / Type 1 error rate is not affected when using fixed, predetermined sample size

Comment: For paired samples, you are looking at differences $A_i - B_i$. Under the nulI that A has same distribution as B, this gives good normal approximation. However, you would need to estimate std even if using CLT is ok. Estimates of std based on small sample size are imprecise. Can you disclose the nature of your variable of interest? You mentioned outliers and skewed distribution - is this the case?

Comment: @jbowman I mentioned that because I didn't had any sample or assumption that I could have made about the underlying distribution, nor any pilot study, therefore I could not estimated the variance if I had no samples. I'll edit my question to make it clear

Comment: @Ute, I can correctly assume that this random variable goes from 0 to + infinite, since it represents time. More reasonably, there is a practical upper limit, that I don't know if I could state this way, but for sure there will not be any time greater than 10.000

Comment: @Ute These RV comes from processing parallel data on several machines on the cloud. I'm studying the time it takes to each task on a CPU core across the cluster get executed, for each kind of dataset. This process has high variability, since there are too much noise on the environment

Comment: @num_39 can you elaborate more on "I'd say just make the sample as large as you possibly can.", please? I understand that if I don't reach a minimum sample size I will loose power, is that correct? Therefore I'd use the greater sample size I can and hope to have enough power to reject the null hypothesis, is that correct? Wouldn't it affect the Alpha somehow? If I had low power, but rejected the null hypothesis anyway, what does it mean? Am I confident enough about my results? I only need to care about sample size and power if I DON'T reject?

Comment: Thanks! How would you then define outliers? Is it possible to detect them? Amd would it make sense to analyze the logarithm of time instead of raw values? (taking log woyld shift focus to mean of log, and you would then consider the difference between 3 and 6 hours equivalent to 3 and 6 days - takes twice as much - rather than equivslent to the difference between 72 and 75 hours) now I see your comment that this is processing time, maybe log transformation is an idea worth to consider. It would quite likely take skew out of your data

Comment: @Ute, not sure, I think it might make sense (?). Overall, I want to reduce the mean time, therefore if the mean log time is reduced, I can conclude that the mean time has reduce, correct? But I couldn't follow your thought, what benefits would I have doing this? About the outliers, I cannot detect them

Comment: If you compare two populations with same mean, but different shape of distribution, it is possible that the means are different after log transformation, unfortunately. But otherwise, log transformation can give "nicer" distributions. Like going from lognormal to normal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147370/discussion-between-mateusvl-and-ute). (StackExchange suggestion, if you prefer). Anyway, understood. So, doing the log transformation would make applying CLT more feasible?